# Japanese kana layout on iPad screen keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, japanese

How can I get ordinary kana layout instead of the sorted あいうえお? It's almost as annoying to use as writing English with the keys ordered like ABC. I need this instead:

[image: kana layout]

Answer (score 1):

To get a different layout you have to find one in the App Store or use a hardware keyboard.